# Collision Detection between a line and a circle in python(tkinter)

Tags: algorithm, math, python-3.x, tkinter, collision-detection

I writing a python program in which a circle bounces off of user drawn lines. There are multiple circles that bounce off the wall. For each one, the shortest distance from the center of the circle and the ball should be calculated. I would prefer if this code was very efficient because my current algorithm lags the computer a lot. If point a is the starting point ,and point b is the end point, and point c is the center, and r is the radius, how would I calculate the shortest distance between the ball? This algorithm should also work if the X coordinate of the ball is out of range of x coordinates in segment AB.

Please post python code

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

lineList is a list with 4 values that contains beginning and end coordinates of the user drawn lines

center is the center of the ball

```
global lineList, numobjects
        if not(0 in lineList):

            beginCoord = [lineList[0],lineList[1]]

            endCoord = [lineList[2]-500,lineList[3]-500]

            center = [xCoordinate[i],yCoordinate[i]+15]

            distance1 = math.sqrt((lineList[1] - center[1])**2 + (lineList[0] - center[0])**2)

            slope1 = math.tan((lineList[1] - lineList[3]) / (lineList[0] - lineList[2]))

            try:
                slope2 = math.tan((center[1] - beginCoord[1])/(center[0]-beginCoord[0]))

                angle1 = slope2 + slope1

                circleDistance = distance1 * math.sin(angle1)

            except:

                #If the circle is directly above beginCoord
                circleDistance = center[1] - lineList[1]


            global numbounces

            if circleDistance < 2 and circleDistance > -2:

                print(circleDistance)

                b = False

                b2=False

                if xCoordinate[i] < 0:

                    xCoordinate[i] += 1

                    speed1[i] *= -1

                    b=True


                elif xCoordinate[i] > 0:

                    xCoordinate[i] -= 1

                    speed1[i] *= -1

                    b=True


                if yCoordinate[i] < 0:

                    yCoordinate[i] += 1

                    speed2[i] *= -1

                    b2=True


                elif yCoordinate[i] > 0:

                    yCoordinate[i] -= 1

                    speed2[i] *= -1

                    b2=True


                if b and b2:

                 #Only delete the line if the ball reversed directions

                    numbounces += 1

                    #Add a ball after 5 bounces

                    if numbounces % 5 == 0 and numbounces != 0:

                        numobjects = 1

                        getData(numobjects)
                    canvas.delete("line")

                    lineList = [0,0,0,0]
```

[image: Diagram of circles]

Comment: "Please post python code..." yes, please do post some code!

Comment: You could show what you have tried. Also this looks more like a math problem rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be correct we are not speaking not about lines, but rather segments.

I would suggest the following idea:

Since the ball is moving in some direction, the only points that might collide with something lie on a 180° arc - the part that is moving forward. Meaning at some point of time when you check for collision you have to check whether any of those points collided with something. The more points you check, the better the precision of the collision in time, but worse the complexity.

Checking the collision: you check whether any of the points is in between the extremes of the segment. You can do this by first checking the coordinates (example is given looking at your drawn line, meaning *A.x < B.x* and *A.y > B.y*) `if (A.x <= point.x <= B.x && A.y >= point.y >= B.y` if the condition satisfies, you check whether the 3 points form a line. Since you have already the coordinates of `A` and `B` you can deduce the equation of the line and check whether the `point` satisfies it.

In short: you check if the `point` satisfies the equation of the line and is inside the rectangle defined by the 2 points.

How to get the points you have to check: assuming `2k+1` is the number of points you want to check at some time, `C` is your center `r` the radius and `V` the vector of motion. Then the number of points from the left side of the direction vector and from the right side will be equal and be `k` (+1 point at the intersection of the circle and the motion vector). Then `90° / k` is one angular division. Since you know the motion vector, you can calculate the angle between it and the horizontal line (let it be `angle`). You keep adding to go left and decrementing to go right from the motion vector the value of `90° / k` exactly `k` times (let us denote this value by `i`) and calculate the position of the `point` by `point.x = C.x + sin(i) * r` and `point.y = C.y + cos(i) * r`.

Sry, I don't know python.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest distance from a circle to a line is the shortest distance from its center to that line, minus the radius of the circle.  If the distance from the center to the line is less than the radius, the line passes through the circle.

Finding the distance from a point to a line is documented many places, including [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

Sorry for not posting Python code, but it is pretty basic.